# Show that $ | S_{2n + 2} | - | S_{2n + 1} | $ follows the same law as the $ X_k $.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

We consider a sequence $ (X_n)_{n \leq 1} $ of mutually independent random variables defined on a probability space $ (\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P}) $  with value in $\{-1,1\}$ and such that, for all $ k \geq 1$ $$ \mathbb{P} (X_k = -1) = \mathbb{P} (X_k = 1) = \frac{1}{2} $$ For all $ n \geq 1 $, we set $ S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n $

**Problem**

Show that $ | S_{2n + 2} | - | S_{2n + 1} | $ follows the same law as the $ X_k $.

For all $w\in\Omega $, we have $ | S_{2n + 2}(w) | - | S_{2n + 1}(w) |\in\{-1,1\} $.  How to show that

$$
\mathbb{P} (| S_{2n + 2}(w) | - | S_{2n + 1}(w) | = -1) = \mathbb{P} (| S_{2n + 2}(w) | - | S_{2n + 1}(w) | = 1) = \frac{1}{2}
$$

An idea please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Condition on $S_{2n+1}$.

$$P(|S_{2n+2}| - |S_{2n+1}| = 1 \mid S_{2n+1})
= P(|S_{2n+1} + X_{2n+2}| - |S_{2n+1}| = 1 \mid S_{2n+1})$$

You can check (with a little bit of casework on whether $S_{2n+1}$ is positive or negative) that no matter what value $S_{2n+1}$ is, this conditional probability is always $1/2$. (It is important to note that it is impossible for $S_{2n+1}$ to be zero!) This then implies that the unconditional probability is also $1/2$.

Comment: $P(|S_{2n+2}| - |S_{2n+1}| = 1)=P(|S_{2n+2}| - |S_{2n+1}| = 1 \mid S_{2n+1})$?